# Facebook Share not working in Safari or Chrome

Tags: facebook, share

I'm using wordpress, I have facebook share button code working with IE and Firefox, just not Chrome or Firefox.

Here is code I took from Facebook website: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

In header.php I have: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<head>`

on single.php I have: `<fb:share-button type="box_count" href="http://<?php echo($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>"></fb:share-button>`

What am I doing wrong?

Example: http://worldinsport.com/calcio-fiorentino-a-bruising-anarchic-and-exhilarating-spectacle-of-sport/

Thanks

Comment: "...code working with IE and Firefox, just not Chrome or Firefox..." you want to edit your question maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://<?php echo($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

OR

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&t=whole description whatever you want to write here','','width=626,height=436'); return false;">
                        <img alt="Share on Facebook" src="/imagesico-facebook-2.png"></a>
```

Comment: That didn't work for me in Chrome, see here: http://worldinsport.com/sportswomen-of-the-past-a-homage-with-vintage-pictures/

Comment: What's happening ? Error, cannot share, what does the link point ot ? correct url ?

Comment: Are you asking what it is pointing to ? `data-href=http://<?php echo($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>`

Comment: This is the html5 link, but could get it working with permalinks.When changing to XFMBL code it would of single.php <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="button_count"></div> Well the domain was http://worldinsport.com

Comment: Does this work for you ? `<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" data-type="button_count"></div>`

Comment: I have used this in past - and worked for me. If it doesn't work can you share the link where it doesn't work ?

Comment: That doesn't work for permalinks, each single page just main domain

Comment: Check here: http://worldinsport.com/sportswomen-of-the-past-a-homage-with-vintage-pictures/ Only share http://worldinsport.com and not the full link: http://worldinsport.com/sportswomen-of-the-past-a-homage-with-vintage-pictures/

Comment: Try this `<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://worldinsport.com/sportswomen-of-the-past-a-homage-with-vintage-pictures/" data-type="button_count"></div>` .
Also, add trailing slash to the url, like I did.

Comment: but I need it to show on all different pages the share button appears on, don't want it just to be  http://worldinsport.com/sportswomen-of-the-past-a-homage-with-vintage‌​-pictures/

Comment: Then use just the main domain `worldinsport.com`

Comment: Here: `<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://worldinsport.com/" data-type="button_count"></div>`

Comment: ok tried that, go here and click the share button and see the problem with the link: http://worldinsport.com/what-we-learnt-from-the-fa-cup-3rd-round/

Comment: Where is the share button ? There is a `like button` and `fb button` that goes to fb page of the website

Comment: It scrolls down the left on single pages, not the homepage

Comment: On left, I can see twitter and googleplus but not fb. Also, just so you know, fb button don't work locally, in case you are testing locally. Hold on ...Does it say "share" ?

Comment: can you take a screenshot of the fb button  ?

Comment: Yea ...works for me...So...what's the problem ? Checked on hits page: http://worldinsport.com/sportswomen-of-the-past-a-homage-with-vintage-pictures/

Comment: Also, sometimes the fb button shows up...soemthing it disappears...not sure if that's because you are testing

Comment: click share, it just shows http://worldinsport.com where it needs to have the rest of the address to share the article on that page. Like http://worldinsport.com/.... followed by content page

Comment: Like this: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=xxxxsdk=joey&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.worldinsport.com%2F30159-"title" l&display=popup etc

Comment: Yes...but with the exact link

Comment: yeah no thumbnail like article preview

Comment: refresh the page. Again here: `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&t=whole description whatever you want to write here','','width=626,height=436'); return false;">
                        <img alt="Share on Facebook" src="/imagesico-facebook-2.png"></a>`

Comment: look here: worldinsport.com/what-we-learnt-from-the-fa-cup-3rd-round doesn't seem to work I need the share button same as befoer with counter. The just has a text link

Comment: Add this on page - `<meta name="description" content="whole description whatever you want to write here.">` Also, add `data-type="button_count"` in anchor tag

Comment: who do I put data-type="button_count"

Comment: Anchor tag `<a data-type="button_count"`

Comment: where in this part do I need to add it: <a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURICo‌​mponent(location.href)+'&t=whole description whatever you want to write here','','width=626,height=436'); return false;"> <img alt="Share on Facebook" src="/imagesico-facebook-2.png"></a>

Comment: I now have <a data-type="button_count" href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURICo‌​mponent(location.href)+'&t=whole description whatever you want to write here','','width=626,height=436'); return false;"> <img alt="Share on Facebook" src="/imagesico-facebook-2.png"></a> but still text and has no counter and clicking does nothing

Comment: it needs to be auto generated for each page

Comment: When I use this code: on single.php I have: <fb:share-button type="box_count" href="http://<?php echo($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>"></fb:share-button> works perfect

Comment: Looks here http://worldinsport.com/share1.png, just does not work with safari or chrome

Comment: I found the problem, it was: <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="**<?php the_permalink() ?>**" data-type="box_count"></div>. for anyone else that has similar problems.

Comment: You should write it as answer ...should help other's